# Qt 6.2.1 OpenSSL 1.1.1l windows 10 not working standalone app TLS initialization failed

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, openssl

I have a small problem with app deployment)
under Qt Creator 5.0.3 base on Qt 5.15.2 (MSVS 2019, 64 bit)
app working perfectly, but when I build release version and move it to other folder app not working and I got TLS initialization failed
windeployqt command below, also I copy libcrypto.dll libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll libeay32.dll libssl-1_1-x64.dll libssl32.dll msvcp140.dll msvcp140_1.dll msvcp140_2.dll from system32 folder

```
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\windeployqt.exe --dir C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin --compiler-runtime --qmldir C:\Project\Qt\WH\qml C:\Project\Qt\build-WH-Desktop_Qt_6_2_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Release\release\WH.exe
```

listddls result for app running under Qt Creator

```
C:\Project\Qt\build-WD-Desktop_Qt_6_2_1_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug\debug\WD.exe
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6Networkd.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6Cored.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6Qmld.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140D.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6Guid.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140_1D.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140_2D.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETUTILS.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SRVCLI.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\tls\qcertonlybackendd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\tls\qopensslbackendd.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\tls\qschannelbackendd.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\system32\libssl-1_1-x64.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UMPDC.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Globalization.dll
C:\Windows\System32\Bcp47Langs.dll
C:\Windows\System32\bcp47mrm.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CFGMGR32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\propsys.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\qtquick2plugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6Quickd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6OpenGLd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6QmlModelsd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQml\WorkerScript\workerscriptplugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6QmlWorkerScriptd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Controls\qtquickcontrols2plugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6QuickControls2d.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6QuickTemplates2d.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Controls\Windows\qtquickcontrols2windowsstyleplugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Controls\Fusion\qtquickcontrols2fusionstyleplugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Controls\Basic\qtquickcontrols2basicstyleplugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Controls\impl\qtquickcontrols2implplugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6QuickControls2Impld.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Layouts\qquicklayoutsplugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6QuickLayoutsd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Templates\qtquicktemplates2plugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Controls\Fusion\impl\qtquickcontrols2fusionstyleimplplugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\NativeStyle\qtquickcontrols2nativestyleplugind.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Window\quickwindowplugind.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwrite.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\imageformats\qgifd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\imageformats\qicnsd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\imageformats\qicod.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\imageformats\qjpegd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\imageformats\qsvgd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6Svgd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\imageformats\qtgad.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\imageformats\qtiffd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\imageformats\qwbmpd.dll
C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\imageformats\qwebpd.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dataexchange.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dcomp.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\netprofm.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\napinsp.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wshbth.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\NLAapi.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\igd10iumd64.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\igdusc64.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxcore.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\npmproxy.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\winhttp.dll
C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\msv1_0.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NtlmShared.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cryptdll.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\edputil.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TextShaping.dll
```

and for standalone app

```
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\WarlocksDuel.exe
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6Qml.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6Gui.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6Network.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6Core.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\VCRUNTIME140.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\VCRUNTIME140_1.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\MSVCP140.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\MSVCP140_1.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\MSVCP140_2.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETUTILS.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SRVCLI.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\platforms\qwindows.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UMPDC.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Globalization.dll
C:\Windows\System32\Bcp47Langs.dll
C:\Windows\System32\bcp47mrm.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CFGMGR32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\propsys.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\qtquick2plugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6Quick.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6QmlModels.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6OpenGL.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQml\WorkerScript\workerscriptplugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6QmlWorkerScript.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\Controls\qtquickcontrols2plugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6QuickControls2.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6QuickTemplates2.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\Controls\Windows\qtquickcontrols2windowsstyleplugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\Controls\Fusion\qtquickcontrols2fusionstyleplugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\Controls\Basic\qtquickcontrols2basicstyleplugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\Controls\impl\qtquickcontrols2implplugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6QuickControls2Impl.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\Layouts\qquicklayoutsplugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6QuickLayouts.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\Templates\qtquicktemplates2plugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\Controls\Fusion\impl\qtquickcontrols2fusionstyleimplplugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\NativeStyle\qtquickcontrols2nativestyleplugin.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\QtQuick\Window\quickwindowplugin.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwrite.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\imageformats\qgif.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\imageformats\qicns.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\imageformats\qico.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\imageformats\qsvg.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\Qt6Svg.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\imageformats\qtga.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\imageformats\qtiff.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
C:\Project\Qt\wh_win_release\bin\imageformats\qwebp.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dataexchange.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dcomp.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\netprofm.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\igd10iumd64.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\igdusc64.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxcore.dll
```

I have no idea what the problem is(
thanks for any advice

-- UPD
thanks @leeharvey1 for help
as hotfix I create cmd file to run my app and set PATH same as Qt Creator set

Comment: as I saw standalone app not use openssl dlls

Comment: It seems the 3 TLS plugin DLLs from the `C:\Qt\6.2.1\msvc2019_64\plugins\tls` folder are loaded before the OpenSSL lib*.DLL files.  Specifically, `qcertonlybackendd.dll`, `qopensslbackendd.dll`, and `qschannelbackendd.dll`.  Thus, if that Qt tls folder is not in your %PATH%, then try copying those 3 DLLs to your target application folder.  Otherwise, monitor your application startup in ProcMon, and look for "Not found" immediately before your process terminates.

Comment: thanks @leeharvey1 I'll try

Comment: @leeharvey1 copy the "tls" folder to the target application folder fixed the error for me, thanks.